# How do I display my facebook pictures on my site

Tags: c#, html, facebook, model-view-controller

Is it possible to programmatically  access my Facebook pictures (through the api?) so I can display them on my own site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
graph.facebook.com/(id of the album not the aid)/photos?access_token=something
```

You just need to get the `id` of the albums.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.
You have to use Facebook's Graph API
Link : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you need give access permission first, then you can access what ever you whant from your account or any account , check the link raj2raaz posted